# make operation between to unsigned number when variables can take negative value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, unsigned, between

How I make one operation Between when I do queries like these:
**types.init and types.end are an unsigned number, and for this case `B.init=0 and B.end=0`**

```
SET @init:=20;
SET @end:=100;

SELECT
  A.`type_id`, B.`type_id`,count(A.id)
FROM
  `types` A ,`types` B 
WHERE
  A.`init` BETWEEN B.`init`- @init
  AND B.`init` +  @init
  AND  A.`end` BETWEEN B.`end`-  @end
  AND B.`end` +  @end
```

then this error occurs:

```
 #1690 - BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`database`.`B`.`init` - (@init))'
```

Comment: You should probably provide a data sample and show what you want the results to be for the row(s) with `B.init=0` and/or `B.end=0`. Or just tell us without the example how the beginning bounds should be calculated when `@init > types.init` and/or `@end > types.end`.

Answer (score 1):

you either need to use [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) to convert to SIGNED, or use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) to check if B.init >= @init.

For the former case your query will look like this:

```
WHERE
  CAST(A.`init` AS SIGNED) BETWEEN CAST(B.`init` AS SIGNED) - @init
  AND CAST(B.`init` AS SIGNED) +  @init
  AND CAST(A.`end` AS SIGNED) BETWEEN CAST(B.`end` AS SIGNED) -  @end
  AND CAST(B.`end` AS SIGNED) +  @end
```

For the latter:

```
WHERE
  A.`init` BETWEEN CASE WHEN B.`init` >= @init THEN B.`init`- @init ELSE 0 END
  AND B.`init` +  @init
  AND  A.`end` BETWEEN CASE WHEN B.`end` >= @end THEN B.`end`-  @end ELSE 0 END
  AND B.`end` +  @end
```